# does my solution satisfy the requirements for a mutual exclusion

Tags: process, semaphore, flags, critical-section, mutual-exclusion

i wrote 2 processes in order to satisfy mutual exclusion but om not sure if it is..
my initial flag value is 0.

```
process 1
while(1){

while flag=1 do{-nothing-}

flag=1

-enter critical section-

flag=0

}

process 2
while(1){

while flag=1 do{-nothing-}

flag=1

-enter critical section-

flag=0

}
```

in fact they are exactly the same.
does those 2 processes satisfy the mutual exclusion?
i cant see what requirement is violated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Process 1                            Process 2

check if flag is 0 - it is
                                          check if flag is 0 - it is
set flag to 1
                                          set flag to 1        

At that point both processes are in their critical sections.
```